# WaveSurfer.js - Edit the Bottom Half of the Waveform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, waveform

I have [WaveSurfer.js](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js) working. I want to make the bottom half more compact so that it looks more like the SoundCloud waveform. I've tried to look at the source code of the WaveSurfer.js but couldn't figure out where and how to edit the source code to make it work.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots and some of your code?